# Generating Function of P Group

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, permutation-cycles, polya-counting-theory

Take G as group of permutations on $n$ elements. It naturally acts on the set $[n]$. Compute the cycle index polynomial of this action of partitioning the permutation into blocks of your own size.

We need to prove that the cycle index polynomial of the above action as
$$P_{G}(x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n) = \sum_{(i)} \frac{\left( \prod_k x_k^{i_k} \right) }{\left( \prod_{k} k^{i_k} i_k! \right)} $$

Here the sum ranges over all partitions $(i)$ represented as $(i_1, i_2, \ldots i_m)$ of $[n]$. Note that $i_k$ is the number of blocks of size $k$ in the partition.

I am unable to get the term in the denominator, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you already have used the fact that you can decompose the symmetric group by cycle type. So for a fixed integer partition first **select** the elements to put in each cycle, so you have
$$\underbrace{\binom{n}{1}\binom{n-1}{1}\cdots \binom{n-i_1+1}{1}}_{i_1\text{ times}}\underbrace{\binom{n}{1}\binom{n-i_1}{2}\cdots \binom{n-i_1-i_2+1}{2}}_{i_2\text{ times}}\cdots $$
which by cancelling out the factorials gives $$\frac{n!}{1!^{i_1}2!^{i_2}\cdots m!^{i_m}}.$$ Now that you have selected the cycles, you have to multiply for in how many ways you can get a cycle of length $j$ the $i_j$ times, that is $(j-1)!^{a_j}$ giving you
$$\frac{n!((1-1)!^{i_1}(2-1)!^{i_2}\cdots (m-1)!^{i_m})}{1!^{i_1}2!^{i_2}\cdots m!^{i_m}}=\frac{n!}{1^{i_1}2^{i_2}\cdots m^{i_m}}.$$
Also, notice that when you selected the $i_j$ cycles, you were giving them an order, you want to take that order out, so yoy have to divide by $i_1!\cdot i_2!\cdots i_m!.$ That gives you the formula you have.
**Edit:** Remember that two permutations have the same cycle type if they have the same cycle structure in the sense that their share the amount of cycles of size $j$ for every $j.$ So you can decompose the sum in adding the permutations with cycle type $(i_1,\cdots ,i_m)$ where $i_j$ is the number of cycles of length $j.$ Notice that fixed this tuple, you have that $1\cdot i_1+2\cdot i_2+\cdots +m\cdot i_m=n$ because you were partitioning the $n$ elements in these cycles. Then what I explained earlier is how you follow.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you just wrote. You know the polynomial? Then what is your question?

Comment: What I know is the cycle index of polynomial G is 
$$P(x_1, x_2, \ldots x_m) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} x_1^{b_1}\ x_2^{b_2} \ldots x_m^{b_m}$$ where $(b_1, b_2, \ldots b_m)$ is the cycle type of $g$.
Now I want to know how |G| became that denominator in the question and how that summation over g in above equation became summation over i in the question

Comment: Ok, I understood that you know that te cycle type in the symmetric group is given by the lengths of the cycles. I explained this in an edit. Follow from the top after reading that.

Comment: I just want to crosscheck whether I am on right track or not. So here the $n!$ the numerator in the term you have written in the proof will get cancelled out by the term $|G|$ whose value is $n!$ as it is acting on $[n]$

Comment: @MathGeek Yes, precisely.

Comment: Now that you have selected the cycles, you have to multiply for in how many ways you can get a cycle of length $j$ the $i_j$ times, that is $(j−1)!^{a_j}$. I didn't understand this step, could you please explain?

Comment: Yes, you are assigning the elements to each cycle, no? Suppose you have a cycle of length $j,$ the number of ways to put $j$ elements in that cycles is $(j-1)!$ because you place, say, the minimum element in the first spot in the cycle and permute the rest. For example, if $j=2$ and the elements are $5,9$ there is just $(2-1)!=1$ cycle, namely $(5,9).$ (Because $(9,5)=(5,9)$ remember that you can rotate inside the cycle.